# All possible permutations of 2 lists

Tags: python

If I have 2 lists:

```
keys= ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5", "key6", "key7", "key8",
         "key9", "key10", "key11", "key12", "key13", "key14", "key15", "key16"]

values= ["val1", "val2", "val3"]

# permutations = [list(zip(x, values)) for x in itertools.permutations(keys, len(values))]
```

I want to get as output all possible permutations (is it 16^3 = 4096?) in such format:

[image]

where [?,?,?] represents a set of possible options within all permutations values.

How can I achieve that in python?

Comment: For 256 permutation, so we need minimum `4 item` in values list so that possible permutation will be possible is 256 (4x4x4x4)

Comment: Your case only full-fill if `permutation with repetition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we are going to create 256 permutation `cases` of `["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]` as `4x4x4x4 = 256` and we create `permutations` list whose each index value, we will add after `shuffling` of `cases`

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

coln = [f'Col{i}' for i in range(1, 257)]
values= ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]
cases = [p for p in itertools.product(values, repeat= 4)]
keys= ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5", "key6", "key7", "key8",
         "key9", "key10", "key11", "key12", "key13", "key14", "key15", "key16"]

permutations = []
for _ in range(16):
    random.shuffle(cases)
    permutations.append(cases)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = permutations, index= keys, columns= coln, dtype= np.object)
print(df)
```

**OUPTUT :**
[image]

Comment: The 256 column number was my mistake, cause my first solution didn't assume that each column will include a set of 3 values, if we have individual value for each column then we'll have 256 columns.
So if I want to do a reduction to 3 values, it will be 4096/3/16=85.33!!! What will be columns number in this case?

Comment: no of columns will be `permutation with repetition` is `3x3x3` which is equal to `27`

Comment: Yes I thought like this at the beginning but it seemed to me a very small amount of columns to include all the possible permutations! don't you think so? Anyway thanks a lot for your solution, using pandas dataframe was a good idea

Comment: One last thing if you can help with, I need all the options of having 10 columns each time... how would you do it? like, the permutations of columns this time

Comment: `condn = np.array([True if i<=9 else False for i in range(256)]);`  
`random.shuffle(condn);`  
`print(df.loc[:, df.columns[condn]]);`